# Updating embedded data, for example sysdata.rda

Tags: r, package

My latest submission to CRAN got bounced back because I have assignments to the global environment which is now frowned upon.

I have an embedded data set (sysdata.rda) that contains configuration parameters based upon state (as in United States) the user resides. I have wanted this embedded data set to be updatable when a new user uses the program. I previously updated this data in the initial function the user uses and made it accessible to the user via global assignment.

I am struggling to figure out how to update this embedded data and make it the default data that the user uses for the remainder of their session.

Previously I housed the data in /data and recently switched it to /R/sysdata.rda as it seemed more suited for that locale. Now I'm not so sure.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you want to ask which state once after they install in the package, or once every time they load the package?

Comment: They load the package with their supplied data and indicate which state they are from (e.g., TX). The package recognizes that their state specific parameters are not a part of the embedded data, calculates them as best it can, and then adds them to the embedded dataset. The problem I'm having is then making that updated dataset available throughout the remainder of the session. I used to do it by assigning it to .GlobalEnv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to do the assignment in an environment other than the global environment.  There are two basic techniques, using `local()` and `<<-` or explicitly creating a new environment:

Working with an explicit environment is straightforward: create the environment and then assign into it like a list:

```
my_opts <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
set_state <- function(value) my_opts$state <- value
get_state <- function() my_opts$state
```

Using `local()` is a little more complex, and requires some tricks with `<<-`

```
set_state <- NULL
get_state <- NULL

local({
  state <- NULL
  get_state <<- function() state
  set_state <<- function(value) state <<- value
})
```

For more info on how `<<-` works see https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/environments, in the "Assignment: binding names to values" section.

Comment: Very helpful! I went the first route. If the function does not find the state's data, it creates an environment and populates that state's branch in the embedded data (a big list with a branch for each state). The updated data is then assigned to the new environment. I'm now running afoul of R CMD check --as-cran for using 'attach' so that the updated data is used after exiting from the function. I'm not sure how to get around that

Comment: Rather than using `attach`, just write a function that accesses the data you want, and call that throughout your code.

Comment: Hmmm. I must be missing something. The data (let's call it 'internal_data') is augmented in a call to a function. I'm not sure how to get augmented 'internal_data' out of that function (I don't want to pass it back as part of what the function returns as that isn't the point of the function). My current poor man's solution (that passes R CMD check --as-cran is to save the object and then load it into the .GlobalEnv.

Comment: @dbetebenner You'd add `set_internal_data` and `get_internal_data` as above, and then use them to set the data once, and then retrieve it from other functions.

Comment: It worked! The key was to create the internal_data as an environment instead of a list! Once that change was made, updating that internal_data within functions persisted! And the code used for environments is 99.9% the same as for a list!

Comment: @hadley Would be awesome if the data chapter of R Packages had a section on accessing internal and external data from package functions ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not have an `foo.R` file in `/data` which loads the data and updates it when the user calls `data(foo)`? This is one of the allowed options for `/data`, but note the following from [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html)

> Note that R code should be “self-sufficient” and not make use of extra functionality provided by the package, so that the data file can also be used without having to load the package.

If you can live with that restriction then `data(foo)` could load the data, update it, and ensure that it is in a specific named object, which you then refer to in your functions.

Comment: Hadn't considered a *.R file in /data. I'll give that a spin